# Modify A <strong> element, but only if it's contained within a particular span ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following little jQuery hack to make any HTML that shows up in `<strong>Warning</strong>` appear big and red:

```
$("strong:contains('Warning')").css("color","red").css("font-size","400%");
```

It works beautifully.  However, it makes *everything* big and red, and I really only want it to make Warnings big and red if they also appear in a span with the id `myWarning`.  For example:

```
<span id="myWarning">
  <div align="left" class="tip">
    <strong>Warning</strong> (I want this to be big and red...)
  </div>
</span>

<strong>Warning</strong> (...but I don't want this to be big and red)
```

How can I enhance my jQuery hack to get it to only modify the CSS of the first "Warning" and not the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prepend a `#myWarning` to your selector?

```
$("#myWarning strong:contains('Warning')").css("color","red").css("font-size","400%");
```

Comment: that seemed too easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myWarning strong").css("color":"red", "font-size":"400%");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want just the first such warning to be big and red?

```
$("strong:contains('Warning')").first().css("color","red").css("font-size","400%");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using jQuery for that? Why not simply use CSS:

```
#myWarning strong { color: red; font-size: 400%; }
```

Comment: Perhaps because `:contains()` didn't make it to CSS3, and he needs to find `strong` tags that have the word "Warning".

Comment: That's true.  This is not a bad answer, but I do want to only make bold the text that has "warning" in it.